# Is there a solution (x,y) to a Pell equation such that $x\equiv \pm 1 \; \mathrm{mod} \; y$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pell-type-equations

I have the following question.
Let $x^2-Ny^2=1$ be a Pell equation (where $N$ is not a square).
Is it possible to find a solution $(x,y)$ such that $x\equiv \pm 1 \; \mathrm{mod} \; y$?
If there exists a solution with $y$ prime, then the answer is yes. But in general?
If the answer is no, are there any sufficient conditions for this to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I can say is... generally, NO. Since you have $x^2-Ny^2=1$, for large $y$ you have $x/y$ is asymptotically $\sqrt{N}$, so $x\mod y$ is about $(\sqrt{N}-\lfloor\sqrt N\rfloor)y$.

Now it looks for the rare $x\mod y=\pm 1$, then we look for $(x,y,N)$ such that $x^2-Ny^2=1$ and $r\mod y=\pm 1$. We are fixing $x,y$ then look for $N$. Let $x=ky+1$ ($ky-1$ is analogous), then we have
$$N=\frac{x^2-1}{y^2}=\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{y^2}=\frac{k(ky+2)}{y}$$

So we only have, either $y$ is odd and $k=ty$, so $N=t(ty^2+2)$. Or $y$ is even and $k=ty/2$, so $N=t(ty^2/4+1)$. Similarly, if $x=ky-1$, when $y$ is odd, we have $k=ty$ and $N=t(ty^2-2)$, or $y$ is even we have $k=ty/2$ and $N=t(ty^2/4-1)$. Using these you could find those rare possibilities such that $x\mod y=\pm 1$.

From here you can prove that $x^2-Ny^2=1$ has at most two such $x,y$, for all $N$.

Comment: None for $N=13,$  partly because the square root is far from an integer, partly because the first pair is large $(649,180).$

Comment: @WillJagy You are right, as I said at most $2$ and $0\le 2$.

Comment: I see, your last line. I would guess, from examples, your one or two solutions must occur as the fundamental Pell solution $(x_0, y_0)$ or the second,  $(x_0^2 + N y_0^2, 2 x_0 y_0)$  unless $\sqrt N$  is very close to an integer.

Comment: @WillJagy You can convince yourself that you can get a stricter condition. I mean you can do more than that. For example, If there are two solutions, the first $y_0$ must be $1$.